# How to convert ANSI to UTF-8 in XMLParser.java

Tags: java, android, xml

I used XMLParser to retrieve data from a url but text error.

```
ANSI => ERROR, UTF-8 => SUCCESS
```

How to convert ANSI to UFT-8 in XMLParser.java ??

**Text example:**

```
Những sét Súng MG cực HOT của LK.Lang-Kinh
```

**Url xml:**

http://truyenucnon.com/thanh.xml

**Text ERROR In my app (default ANSI):**

```
Nhá»¯ng sÃ©t SÃºng MG cá»±c HOT cá»§a LK.Lang-Kinh
```

**Text SUCCESS UTF-8:**

```
Những sét Súng MG cực HOT của LK.Lang-Kinh
```

**XMLParser.java**

```
package com.ucnon.videohai;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;

public class XMLParser {
    static InputStream is = null;
    // constructor
    public XMLParser() {

    }

    /**
     * Getting XML from URL making HTTP request
     * @param url string
     * */
    public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
        String xml = null;

        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);



} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "utf-8"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            xml = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }
        // return XML
        return xml;
    }

    /**
     * Getting XML DOM element
     * @param
     * */
    public Document getDomElement(String xml){
        Document doc = null;
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try {

            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

            InputSource is = new InputSource();
                is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
                doc = db.parse(is);
                is.setEncoding("UTF-8");

            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                return null;
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                return null;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                return null;
            }

            return doc;
    }

    /** Getting node value
      * @param elem element
      */
     public final String getElementValue( Node elem ) {
         Node child;
         if( elem != null){
             if (elem.hasChildNodes()){
                 for( child = elem.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling() ){
                     if( child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE  ){
                         return child.getNodeValue();
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
         return "";
     }

     /**
      * Getting node value
      * @paramElement node
      * @paramkey string
      * */
     public String getValue(Element item, String str) {
            NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);
            return this.getElementValue(n.item(0));
        }


}
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the charset in your website access:

```
xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity, Charset.forName("utf-8"));
```

Comment: OMG. Thank you so much! it work :)) I use code `xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity, "utf-8"); `